# Is there a way to add contacts on a smartphone agenda through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

someone knows if there’s a way to add contacts on smartphone agenda through JavaScript? Not like an Ionic/Cordova App, but from a regular website.

I’ve made some research and get two matches: People API from Mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/gather_and_modify_data/Updating_phone_contacts_from_the_web), not supported on the pther browsers yet, and the Google People API.

I just would like to know if there are other options for that.